# Xen 4.1.2 error trying to set up remus

Tags: backup, virtual-machine, opensuse, xen

When I attempt to set up remus between two machines I get an error in the remus log file, I cant understand why it occurs, I have the same vms running on both systems, so attempted replication shouldnt be an issue. The Log file is as follows

```
Disk is not replicated: phy:/dev/loop0,xvda,w
Disk is not replicated: phy:/dev/loop1,xvdb,w
tc qdisc add dev vif1.0 ingress
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
tc filter add dev vif1.0 parent ffff: proto ip pref 10 u32 match u32 0 0 action
mirred egress redirect dev ifb0
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
We have an error talking to the kernel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/remus", line 219, in <module>
     run(cfg)
  File "/usr/bin/remus", line 125, in run
     bufs.append(BufferedNIC(vif))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/xen/remus/device.py", line 326, in __init__
    self.setup()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/xen/remus/device.py", line 358, in setup
    self.bufdev.install(self.vif)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/xen/remus/device.py", line 184, in install
    'dev %s' % (vif.dev, self.devname))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/xen/remus/util.py", line 71, in runcmd
    proc.returncode)
xen.remus.util.PipeException: tc failed (errmsg: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
We have an error talking to the kernel): 2, No such file or directory
```

The remus command used to get this file is as follows:

```
remus -i 100 sles11-sp1-xm BackupMachineIP >/var/log/xen/domU-sles11-sp1-24-09-12.log 2>&1 &
```

BackupMachineIP is setup as the name for the IP address of the backup device, the contents of xm list and the loopback device setups on each machine are as follows:

### xm list

Primary:

```
 Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
 Domain-0                                     0 1036702     8     r----- 411617.9
 sles11-sp1                                       512     4                 0.0
 sles11-sp1-xm                                1   256     1     -b----     77.0
 sles11-sp2                                       512     4                 0.0
 sles11-sp2-xm                                2   256     1     -b----     62.0
```

Secondary:

```
 Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
 Domain-0                                     0  1400     2     r-----     73.1
 sles11-sp1-xm                                1   256     1     -b----     11.6
 sles11-sp2-xm                                2   256     1     -b----     14.0
```

### losetup

Primary:

```
/dev/loop0: [0808]:337772 (/tmp/base/sles11sp1/sles11sp1.img)
/dev/loop1: [0808]:337773 (/tmp/base/sles11sp1/swap)
/dev/loop2: [0808]:337779 (/tmp/base/sles11sp2/sles11sp2.img)
/dev/loop3: [0808]:337780 (/tmp/base/sles11sp2/swap)
```

Secondary:

```
/dev/loop0: [0805]:2109411 (/tmp/base/sles11sp1/sles11sp1.img)
/dev/loop1: [0805]:2109412 (/tmp/base/sles11sp1/swap)
/dev/loop2: [0805]:1840010 (/tmp/base/sles11sp2/sles11sp2.img)
/dev/loop3: [0805]:1840012 (/tmp/base/sles11sp2/swap)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably your kernel doesn't have the mirred kernel module loaded. Usually it's not even compiled with the kernel, so you have to compile and load it. Quite silly that RTNETLINK answers a simple ENOENT (No such file or directory) if the module is not loaded, it took me almost a day to find out why it doesn't work.